# How do I show progress bar while unzipping a folder in C# console application

Tags: c#, zip, progress-bar, extract, unzip

For my C# console application that is unzipping and relocating a folder, I am using the ExtractToDirectory function from ZipFile class to unzip the folder to a certain location.
I want to know if there is a way to show the progress of the unzipping and maybe later to show the progress of the moving of the folder.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Progress Bar not available for zipfile? How to give feedback when program seems to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430559/progress-bar-not-available-for-zipfile-how-to-give-feedback-when-program-seems)